# Calling anchor function in the background

Tags: anchor, transactions, pda, anchor-client

How do I call a anchor function without having the end user approve/sign in their wallet?

During development in my anchor project, I was able to create tests where I can call anchor functions without having a wallet pop up and approve/sign the transaction. I'm starting the process of moving the ideas to my Vue frontend but when I try to call the same function, Phantom wallet pops up to approve/sign the transaction. Since the paying account will not be the end user (it will be an internal private account) there is no need for the user to approve this transaction. I just want it to be called in the background when an end user does some action. This is what my test code looks like in the anchor project. Works perfectly when running tests there.

```
await program.value.methods.create_account(data_one,data_two)
        .accounts({
            account: accountKey,
            manager: managerKey,
        })
        .rpc();
```

When I move this over to my Vue application Phantom wallet pops open and needs me to confirm. How can I run this call this without the pop up?